# SAML on Android

Tags: java, android, authentication, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to implement SSO in my Android application. I already have an Identity Provider (Duo Access Gateway), which is currently being used in my company. I'm unable to find any guides or explanations on how to go about this.

My understanding so far is that I need a service provider, but an Android native app can't perform that task. So I would need to create a web app to act as SP, load this SP in a WebView/Custom Chrome Tab, authenticate the user there, and then pass the SAML assertion back to the application?

The problem is I have no idea on where to start and how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml-too/) which is js.

Your other option is using something like Auth0 or Okta and then going OpenID Connect to Auth0 and SAML to Duo.

They both have Android examples.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

So the plan is to set up Auth0 as my Service Provider and use Duo Access Gateway as the identity provider. That seems pretty straightforward and simple. My problem is going from SAML Assertion to OAuth/OpenID token. I've seen that suggested multiple times, but no instructions on how to do it. Do you have any examples/tutorials?

Comment: Auth0 does that for you. Basically, you can add Duo as an option to your Lock screen (the Auth0 login). Then you go OpenID Connect to Auth0 (the library does this for you) and then Auth0 handles the SAML for you to Duo.